# Product and factors of multiple values in Java

Tags: java, do-while, factorization

The program I'm trying to write needs to input a user-defined number of Int values and produce the product of those values, and then determine all of the factors of that product. The values will be input through a Do-While Loop until the user enters a negative number, and then all the positive numbers will be multiplied together to form a product in the form of a Double. I'm fairly certain I can figure out how to get the factors of the product, but when it comes to finding the actual product I'm completely at a loss. Here is the code I've written so far, minus my failed attempts at producing a product.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int Value;
    double Product;

    do
    {
        System.out.print("Value: ");
        Value = in.nextInt();
    }
    while (Value>=0);
}
```

This is all I've been able to figure out, looping the Value prompt until a negative Int is entered. As far as getting the product I've tried If-Statements both inside and outside the loop, but either my code is wrong or my statements are wrong, or more likely I'm just trying the wrong method. **I'm not asking anybody to write the code for me**, but if somebody could point me in the right direction I would very much appreciate it.

What tips would you suggest to determine the product from an unknown number of user-difined values?

Comment: Hint: `1` multiplied by anything becomes that value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set `product` variable to be initially equal to **1** and multiply the value of `product` by the input number each time the user writes a number.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int value;
    double product=1;

    do
    {
        System.out.print("Value: ");
        value = in.nextInt();
        product *= value //product= product * value;
    }
    while (value>=0);

    System.out.println("Product is: "+product);
}
```

Comment: @PM77-1 The guy was pretty much there. He was just missing 1 statement. He deserves the help.

Comment: Code-Guru: Added at the bottom of my post for clarification. I'll do that from now on, thanks.